# tomcat how to keep temporary files?

Tags: java, tomcat, temporary-files

I found out that when I call:

```
File.createTempFile();
```

in tomcat7 my temp file is created. BUT...
it is deleted immediately after the Thread creating this file ends.

The default behavior of JVM should be to keep these files until it is shutdown. Apparently tomcat overwrites this behavior. Is there any switch to change this so that tomcat would keep the temp file?

Comment: Files created through `File.createTempFile()` aren't automatically deleted by the JVM. Something else is causing your temporary files to be deleted.

Comment: Tomcat makes no changes to `File.createTempFile`'s behavior. What does your code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.createTempFile("filename","format");
```

will create a file with scope for that particular thread only.

May be manually calling like

```
File.deleteOnExit()
```

might help.

Comment: What "scope" are you referring to? A "temporary" file isn't deleted *at all* if you don't call it's `deleteOnExit()` method.

Comment: I think it deletes as soon as the thread expires without calling deleteOnExit(), "scopes" = thread expiry time.

Comment: Have you tried? On my Linux, Java7 box the file stays even after the VM terminates.

Comment: `File.createTempFile` does not arrange for the later removal of the temporary file. You have to do that manually.

Comment: weird I have also a linux box (OREL) + JDK 1.7 and my files gets deleted after thread ends... Maybe it is some JVM flag?

Comment: Turns out i am an idiot :) was deleteing the files myself... :D